# LogShipping replicated database

Tags: replication, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication, log-shipping

We use transaction replication to replicate our production database to another server(server 1) for reporting purpose. For a standby copy, we also logship the main database to another server (server 2).

Last week I had to reinitialise the standby copy. 
However, after restoring the production database on Server 2; under the replication publications node, I see the database has been published, and under that, I see the subscriber server.

[image]

The Server 2 is not configured for replication.  Because the secondary database is on Standby\Read Only mode, the system is not allowing me to make any modification.

How can I remove the replication configuration from the secondary server?

Many thanks

Comment: Could you try the following command on Server 2 and see if it will remove the replication? EXEC sp_removedbreplication 'DB_Name'

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I said the database is Standby\read only mode the command will not work.

Comment: Hi, would like to clarify on your question. There are 3 servers involved - Publisher server that replicates to server 1, and server 1 does log shipping to server 2. Did i get it right?

Comment: There are 3 serves involved. Publisher replicates to Server 1. Same publisher server logshipp to Server 2

Comment: Ah, I see. When doing the restoration of the DB from Production to Server 2, did you included the "KEEP_REPLICATION" settings?

Comment: No, I didn't check KEEP_REPLICATION

Comment: Ah... I am sorry as I am afraid my knowledge is limited in this area. However, using the mirroring concept and some google I did, since the publisher server log ship to server 2, then it should be normal for the replication settings to be appearing on server 2. This is because it will be required after a failover. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/log-shipping-and-replication-sql-server . Judging from this, you shouldn't be removing the replication away from Server 2?